# can't install android app onto phone

Tags: android, installation, adt, device

I've gone through ALL the tutorials I could find and still no luck.

I am simply trying to install an android app onto my Nexus 4, Android version 4.4.3 ... and would love some help.

It can not find the device that is plugged into the computer.
Actually NOTHING happens when I plug the phone into the computer, shouldn't it show me in the notifications that the device is connected?

I just downloaded and installed Eclipse/ADT yesterday and am unsure if I would need to install any drivers etc.

My phone does have the developer options in settings, and USB Debugging is checked!

When I run the app, the android device chooser pops up.

[image]

Comment: Try a different cable. Some micro USB cables appear to be charge-only.

Comment: Problem Solved! The cable appears to be broken (or something similar) as I tried a friend's cable and everything is working correctly! THANKS!!!